# mysql doesn't create /var/run/mysqld directory

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ubuntu-16.04

I created a `/etc/tmpfiles.d/mysqld.conf`, `/etc/tmpfiles.d/mysql.conf`, `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/mysql.conf`, `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/mysqld.conf`

with the content

**`d /var/run/mysqld 0755 mysql mysql -`**

yet after rebooting `/var/run/mysqld` doesn't get created. I'm on `ubuntu 16.04` and mysql-server version is 5.7.

Any idea why it doesn't create the directory?

Comment: Do you have apparmor enabled on your system ?  Check the logs, you may found something corresponding to your file

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it wasn't the problem with /var/run/mysqld dir. Instead I had to run `mysqld --initialize` and its safe since its a new installation. Once the initialize finished, /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service - RuntimeDirectory created a mysqld dir under /var/run/